# SED - get second line from buffer space

Tags: sed

I have a config file that has two lines like such:

```
some data...
some data...
https://localhost:8443 # default config
https://abc.client.mycorp.com:8443
some more data....
```

I want to print the **second** line. However since the FQDN is set dynamically I never know in advance what it will be so I could (potentially) setup a more exact regex

when I run the following **both** lines get returned

```
sed -n 's/.*\(https.*[0-9]\).*/\1/p' my.conf
```

What needs to be added to the sed command so I only get the second line?
 `sed '1d'` works but I suspect there is something more elegant.

Comment: why need to use `sed` for this task? there are better tools, for example: `head -n+2 my.conf | tail -n+2`. wait for somebody to show `awk` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '/https.*[0-9]/h;${g;s/.*\(https.*[0-9]\).*/\1/p;}' my.conf
```

- selection of lines and print the second (last).
- assuming there are (and only) 2 https like your request specify

**Explaination**

- select line with pattern `'/https.*[0-9]/` and copy it to holding buffer `h` (not append, replace the content with current line)
- at the end `${   }`
- get holding buffer to working buffer `g` (so  retreive the last stored line)
- adapt the format `s/.*\(https.*[0-9]\).*/\1/` using group reference `\1 -> \( \)` and print the modified content `p`

Comment: Perfect ! Would it be too much trouble for you to break down the code so I could understand the answer better ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `awk`

```
awk -F"https" 'NF>1{split($2,a," ");if (++b==2) print FS a[1]}' my.conf
https://abc.client.mycorp.com:8443
```

It finds lines with `https` and prints only the second one of them.

```
cat file
Some line with data
url=https://localhost:8443 # default config
url=https://abc.client.mycorp.com:8443
Some more data
```

```
awk -F"https" 'NF>1{split($2,a," ");if (++b==2) print FS a[1]}' file
https://abc.client.mycorp.com:8443
```

Answer (score 1):

there are thousands of ways to do this.

as i've shown in comment:

```
head -n+2 my.conf | tail -n+2
```

but after 10 seconds, found out sed is good too:

```
sed -n '2p' my.conf
```

i think awk could be able to do the trick too. forgive me i couldn't remember the variable name.

Comment: this is not print the 2nd line but the second line that contain `https`

Answer (score 1):

Your command

```
sed -n 's/.*\(https.*[0-9]\).*/\1/p'
```

this command matches any lines with a pattern https followed by a digit.It therefore means that sed will print all lines whether 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. with this pattern. **Another** solution elegant solution would be

```
sed '2!d' my.conf
```

this is saying whenever you read a line and it is not line 2 delete it. Hence only line 2 is printed. **Nevertheless, no changes are made to the actual file.**

**EDIT:** A solution using awk

```
awk 'NR==2' my.conf
```

Comment: The `{print}` is redundant; it's the default action.

Comment: thank you jens..trying to get a grip with awk...i edited answer

Comment: the second solution is not doing what is requested (print the second line **with** `https` inside). So elegant but not relevant

Answer (score 1):

To just print the 2nd line from a file would be:

```
awk 'NR==2' file
```

but assuming you actually want to print the 2nd string that matches the regexp you specified in your sed command:

```
awk 'match($0,/https.*[0-9]/) { if (++cnt == 2) print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }' file
```